# Replace curly braces separated by a newline with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace this

```
    },   <-here there is a \n
    {
```

with

```
}{
```

Doesn't matter about \n

I've tried this :

```
sed "s/},\n{/}{/g"
```

but doesn't work.

I've tried other strange solutions but don't work as well because in the file there are a lot of others rows that start with `{`.

Could you please suggest some solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

Sample `test.txt` file:

```
afa
asdasd
},
{
sdfasd
},
{
```

---

```
sed '/},$/{ N; s/,\n{/{/; }' test.txt
```

The output:

```
afa
asdasd
}{
sdfasd
}{
```

Answer (score 3):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. What you're trying to do crosses 2 lines and so is not a job for sed. Just use awk, e.g.:

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/},\n{/,"}{")} 1' file
```

The above will work portably with all awks in all shells on all UNIX systems (the sed solutions you have so far will only work in some seds and so are not portable).

Comment: This is interesting, but also removes any blank lines in the file.

Comment: @TimMalone As the OP says in the question - "Doesn't matter about \n". If you have a question similar to the one here but which has requirements for retaining blank lines then post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-z` option for `sed` which separates lines by null characters instead of newlines. You may want to use it with `-u` if it's a particularly large file.

```
sed -z "s/},\n{/}{/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/},\n\s*{/}{/;P;D' file
```

Create a moving window of two lines and replace the newline separated pattern when appropriate.